# Generating CORBA IDL from Java source files?

Tags: java, corba, jcr, idl

Considering that `idlj` is a tool implementing a transform in which an OMG IDL input can be transformed to a Java source code output, is there a converse transform, and a corresponding tool available, something with which IDL could be generated from Java source code?

I ask out of the interest of developing an IDL mapping for JCR. Given the source code of the JCR reference model in JSR-283, if it would be possible to generate IDL for so many interfaces and exception types as are defined in that source code, it could simply the task considerably -- thus somewhat simplifying the task of making JCR available to non-Java client applications, albeit then incorporating the CORBA architecture, in its relative complexity.

If there is not such a tool, though I'm not sure I'd be prepared to be design an IDL generator for Java, but if such a tool was designed, certainly then it could serve to simplify the "IDL for JCR" definition task, considerably,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. The *rmic -idl* tool does exactly that. But you have to start with a Java remote interface.